# Odoo 10 - Disable default "My opportunities" filter in CRM

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

When user checks sales flow (opportunities) in Odoo 10 CRM module, the "My opportunities" filter is enabled by default.

Is it possible to configure behaviour so user has no such filter and he/she sees all opportunities?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to remove default filter "My Opportunities" on the CRM leads by **Editing Action**.

## 1. Edit action from UI

Activate developer mode. and from the debug edit the action.

[image]

## 2. Edit action from XML

in below record **search_default_assigned_to_me** is responsible for setting the default filter.

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="crm.crm_lead_opportunities_tree_view">
    <field name="context">{
        'default_type': 'opportunity',
        'default_user_id': uid,
        'search_default_assigned_to_me': 0,
        }
    </field>
</record>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the context of the `crm_lead_opportunities_tree_view` action to remove the default search filter. So we still are using that particular action to land on the crm opportunity tree view, but with our customized context.

And, actually, I forgot to add 'default_user_id' and 'default_type'.
This should work.

`<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="crm.crm_lead_opportunities_tree_view">
    <field name="context">{
        'search_default_assigned_to_me': 0,
        'default_type': 'opportunity',
        'default_user_id': uid
    }</field>
</record>`

Comment: Please add some text to describe what this is doing.

Answer (score 1):

And here an answer without using debug mode and changing odoo default actions: Just create a filter for yourself, for example "group by stage and group by salesman" and save it as default filter.